# Using multiple WinExists in IF statement

Tags: autohotkey

I want to validate that several windows **don't** exist. I'm not sure how to tie multiple together. I've tried with and without the outer parenthesis. What are my options here?

For example.

```
xclude:= "Salesforce - Google Chrome"
xclude_ff:= "Salesforce - Mozilla Firefox"

if (!WinExist(Ticket_Out,,xclude) && !WinExist(Ticket_Out,,xclude_ff))
  {
    msgbox, Neither window exists, proceed...
  }
else
  {
    msgbox, one of the windows exists!
    return
  }
```

Is the only way nested if?

EDIT: I discovered that my initial script had a semi colon at the end of the if statement line with no space. So I was receiving an illegal character error. Removing this allows the script to work.

Comment: The code there will work as expected, you don't need to nest if statements. You probably have problems with the titles you're trying to match. Double check them.

Comment: I double checked them. I can even extrapolate this out and go for `if !WinExist(Ticket_Out,,xclude)` .... else if `!WinExist(Ticket_Out,,xclude_ff)` ... `else msgbox` It properly diverts to each one. I can't get it to go into combined. Does  AHK version matter?